# Mysql order by rand and setting user variable

Tags: mysql

Can anyone explain what is happening with the following SQL?  I understand order by rand is not a good practice, but I am interested in an explanation of why this is happening

```
create database test_views_rand;
use test_views_rand;
create table test_table (number int);

insert into test_table  values (1), (2), (3), (4);

select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
# selects a random number from 1 - 4
select @test;
# Always gives 4, regardless of what the actual number was in the select query
```

Just in case it isn't clear, the first select statement is random as expected. The second select statement always gives 4, regardless of the outcome of the first select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignments are done before order by like @bw_üezi said.

```
select @test := number, @aa:=(@a:=@a+1), @a, @r 
  from test_table, (select @a:=0) a 
 order by (@r:=rand());
```

results

```
|| 3 || 3 || 3 || 0.160410950109745  ||
|| 4 || 4 || 4 || 0.0159870376959322 ||
|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 0.161011773311544  ||
|| 2 || 2 || 2 || 0.928689247862146  ||
```

and then `select @test,@aa,@a,@r` results

```
|| 2 || 2 || 4 || 0.015987037695932  ||
```

How `@aa` can ever be 4 if in the end it is only 2?

This is because of the bugfix: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16861

> updates variable from the result_field value when being sent to a client.

User-variable assignments that are not part of the expression in the select part are done twice (at least for last row, not sure about others)

Manipulating user-variables inside query can often yield in unexpected results.

You are better off using query:

```
select @test := (select number from test_table order by rand() limit 1);
```

or

```
set @test := (select number from test_table order by rand() limit 1);
```

Comment: `ORDER BY rand()` is an anomaly because rand() doesn't actually exist in the table. For any normal `order by`, e.g. `select @test := number, @a:=@a+1 from test_table, (select @a:=0) a order by number desc;` - this shows `ORDER BY number` done first, directly affecting the output of `@a`. But good find on the bug. RAND() is not determinate so the sort in temp-table is a spanner in the mix.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - Updated the Answer, it seems like `rand()` is evaluated before sorting is done and it acts the same as extra field in the table (just different with each query)

Answer (score 2):

(your code is missing an `INSERT` keyword)
On my version of MySQL (5.5), these are my results

```
drop table if exists test_table;
create table test_table (number int);

insert into test_table (number) values (1),(2),(3),(4);

select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
# selects a random number from 1 - 4
select @test;
```

Results

```
3,4,3,1,4,3,4,3,1,3
```

However, if you order by rand(now()) and do it quickly, it will stick at 4....3....2....4... because it is no longer `random`, you have given it a specific seed.

If you run it with **order by rand(1), the answer is ALWAYS the same**, because you have asked it to seed based on 1 consistently.

---

To see what RAND() produces (which is what is used to sort the rows), check out this query:

```
select rand() from (
select 1 union all select 2 union all
select 1 union all select 2 union all
select 2
) x;
```

Run it many times.  Then swap for rand(now()) and run it many times quickly.  Then swap for rand(1) and run again.

---

To see how this actually affects your query, just remove the ORDER BY and see the magic happening.

```
select @test := number, rand(2) from test_table
order by rand(2)
```

Change rand(2) to rand(1) or just rand() *(remember to change in both places)*.  Watch the 2 columns closely.  As for how `@test :=` works, it *does* set it to the first row. BUT, it continues to set it for *EVERY* row, and ends up with the value set at the last row encountered.

Comment: @richard are you also running the select @test; statement? Is this reflecting the result of the first select statement?

Comment: I still dont understand - select @test := number, rand(2) from test_table order by rand(2); has different values for rand(2), so the order by for the user variable seems it should be by these values and not a filesort.  I'm not seeing why the first result from the query is not assigned to @test.

Comment: But in select @test := number, rand(3) from test_table  order by rand(3); select @test; 1 is the last row - or is it calculating the variable value before it orders?  If so, why does select @test := number from test_table order by number <> 4; select @test; result in @test being set to 3? (I understand how the ordering works, it is the inconsistent variable setting I am having trouble understanding)

Comment: Aha! On my version of MySQL, in the first case, @test contains 4, not 1 as I expected.  @Mamsaac has an answer with my expected output as well, so I am guessing there is something odd in my version (5.1.56) of MySQL.  Thanks for your patience in explaining this to me!

Comment: Nope, order by rand(3) gives me 3, 2, 4, 1, but @test is set to 4

Comment: See `Imre L`'s answer. I wasn't aware of that bug.

Answer (score 2):

the assignment @test := number is done before order and limit.

As Richard points out this is not quite right. Explain path shows "Using filesort".
 On the other hand Imre points out there was bug in MySQL with `ORDER BY rand()`

Comment: If that is true, I would expect select @test := number from test_table  order by number <> 2 limit 1; select @test; to bring back 1 - however, it brings back 2

Comment: @tim Is this in reply to my answer? order by `number <> 2` sorts by a virtual column equal to `number <> 2`. Since it is a boolean expression (true/false), false(0) comes before true(1). The only row for which it is false is when number=2, so it is the FIRST row. LIMIT 1 means it only ever sees that row, so you will ALWAYS get @test =2.

Comment: processing order: WHERE > ORDER BY > SELECT (and assign)> up to LIMIT

Comment: looks like nobody is completely wrong and the real explanation is a bit more complicated. So just stay friends ;-)

Comment: `select @test := number, @a:=@a+1 from test_table, (select @a:=0) a order by number desc;` - this shows `ORDER BY number` being done (directly affecting) the output of `@a`, hence the comment above that `ORDER BY > SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't true

If I run this query

```
select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
```

I get different results.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? I am using 5.1.56

Comment: Mine is 5.1.36. Try to do order by rand(now()) and tell me if something changes

Comment: No luck with rand(now()) either

Comment: I've seen your answer. I had supposed it was just a timmow typo.

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly fine for me.

Chances are that you didn't try enough times or something. Output of my cases:

```
mysql> select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
+-----------------+
| @test := number |
+-----------------+
|               4 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @test;
+-------+
| @test |
+-------+
|     4 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
+-----------------+
| @test := number |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @test;
+-------+
| @test |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? I am on 5.1.56

Comment: This is the output I am expecting, and not seeing on my version of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down

This creates a database on your server called 'test_views_rand', all of our tables will be in this database
    Create database test_views_rand;

This command says to use the newly created database 'test_views_rand'

```
use test_views_rand;
```

This command creates the first table called 'test_table' in the 'test_view_rand' database.  The table contains only one column named 'number' which holds integers

```
create table test_table (number int);
```

This command inserts four entries into the 'test_table' table.  This command isn't syntax I normally see.

```
into test_table  values (1), (2), (3), (4);
```

This command selects all the numbers from the 'test_table' table and mixes the order in which the results appear ie. 1,3,2,4 or 4,2,3,1, or 1,2,3,4, etc. and picks the number out of these four so you get one number.

```
select @test := number from test_table order by rand() limit 1;
```

Since we inserted the entires 1,2,3,4 it will return 4 since that is the top entry?

```
select @test;
```

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi  I have never used it, but from a quick google I gathered that it simply ordered the resulting rows randomly.

Comment: @Richard, yes, I understand that as explained in my post.  Using rand() however is undesirable because of the seed issue you mentioned.  Hopefully timmow will be able to generate a random number in whatever programming language he is using (if any)